# Assign a map to a method invocation

Tags: groovy

I have a method which returns a map.

I want to assign variables to specific values in the map returned from the method...

```
[myA:a, myB:b] = myMethodWhichReturnsAMap()
print myA;
print myB;
```

So the map returns a map with a and b in it.  I want to assign myA and myB in the one statement.  Is this possible?

Comment: Can You put it please in a wider context?

Comment: @Opal I have updated question. Will update again if not clear.

Comment: So why not: `def m = myMethodWhichReturnsAMap(); print m.myA; print m.myB`?

Comment: I don't want to keep having to do m.myA, m.myB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not supported. You can return multiple values from a method and assign them to variables in a single statement like this

```
def foo() {
  [1, 2]
}

def (myA, myB) = foo()
```

But the function that returns multiple values must return them in a `List`, it doesn't work with a `Map`.

Answer (score 3):

No. [Groovy multiple assignment](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Multiple+Assignment) currently only works in collections and arrays. You may try getting every value from the map (with `.values()`, which doesn't care about ordering) or using `with` to get the keys from the map:

```
def fn = { [a: 1, b: 2] }
def (a, b) = fn().with { [a, b] }

assert a == 1
assert b == 2
```

If it is a very common use case, you may want to add a bit of metaprogramming:

```
def fn = { 
    def m = [a: 1, b: 2]
    m.getMetaClass().getAt = { List keys -> 
        delegate.findAll { it.key in keys }*.value 
    }
    m
}

def (a, b) = fn()['a', 'b']

assert a == 1
assert b == 2
```